# Arduino Serial Port, data don't arrive

Tags: c#, c++, c, arduino

I have a problem with my Arduino (Yun)
Basically I would like the board communicate its data with a C# program
Loading this on Arduino:

```
int Loop=0;
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
    Serial.println(" Data loop = " + String(Loop));
    Loop++;
    delay(500);
}
```

And this is the C# code:

```
SerialPort ArduinoSerial = new SerialPort("COM7", 9600);
ArduinoSerial.Open();
while (true)
{
    string data= ArduinoSerial.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

Every time I start the program will come something unpredictable
Sometimes there is nothing written, sometimes this:
5
6
7
10
_
But why? Sometimes data is lost, sometimes do not "arrive" anything
Trying with an emulator of serial monitor (puTTY) data arrives
Then why? Where am I wrong?

Comment: Hmm.. is this a LF/CRLF thingy?

Comment: Can you examine the data actually received?  Look for 0x0d or 0x0A in the data stream.  Which byte is causing the issue?

Comment: Have you tried to launched first the C# prog and reset the Arduino ? The garbage can be a packet splitted.

Comment: an obvious test is to get something like [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) (you want putty.exe) and make sure that your arduino is actually sending data that makes sense / at all

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:
 Console.WriteLine(a);

to
Console.WriteLine(data);

it should help!